# ruleta rusa en pseint

Tags: pseint, pseudocódigo

Estoy creando un juego de la ruleta rusa, son 2 jugadores y cuatro partidas
en total, 2 por cada jugador de manera alternada. La posición de la bala se saca al azar.
el pseudocódigo esta listo digamos, el único detalle es que a la hora de que salga la posición
en donde se encuentra la bala tiene que cerrar ese ciclo y asignar un 0 al jugador que
perdió, si alguien pudiera ayudarme con eso, le agradecería ya que no he podido solucionarlo
les muestro lo que sería para el primer jugador

```
Escribir "======================================"
Escribir "|             RULETA RUSA            |"
Escribir "======================================"
Escribir ""
Escribir "Ingrese el nombre del jugador 1:"
leer jugador1
Escribir "Ingrese el nombre del jugador 2:"
leer jugador2
repetir
Limpiar Pantalla

ESCRIBIR "           Orden del Juego"
Escribir  "1. inicia primer partida del jugador 1"
Escribir  "2. inicia primer partida del segundo 2"
Escribir  "3. inicio segunda partida del jugador 1"
Escribir  "4. inicio segunda partida del jugador 2"
leer opc


    Segun opc Hacer
      1:
        Escribir "***********************************************" 
        escribir"        PRIMER JUEGO DEL PRIMER JUGADOR"
        Escribir "***********************************************"
        Escribir ""

        Escribir "   ************************"
        Escribir "   |   Jugador   " jugador1  "  |"
        escribir "   ************************"
        escribir ""

        Escribir "Partida número # " parti
        parti<-parti+1


        Para part<-1 Hasta 8 Con Paso 1 Hacer


            escribir""
            ESCRIBIR "Intento # " part
            Escribir ""
            num <- azar(8)+1
            numVerificar<- azar(4)+1


            escribir "Posición " num


            si  num<>numVerificar
                nAzar=azar(10)+1
                escribir "Puntos obtenidos: " nAzar
                resTotal= resTotal+nAzar

            FinSi
            si num=numVerificar Entonces

                resPerdi= 0 
                Escribir" ========================================"
                Escribir" |              Perdiste                |"
                escribir" |         Posición de la bala:       " numVerificar " |"
                Escribir" ========================================"

                escribir "Puntos: " resPerdi
                Escribir ""


            FinSi
            Esperar Tecla
        FinPara

        Escribir ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tu proceso sera similar para todas las partidas deberias crear un subproceso de esta manera estarás economizando código.

```
Subproceso disparo
    Escribir "Partida número # " parti
    parti<-parti+1
    Para part<-1 Hasta 8 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        Escribir ""
        Escribir "Intento # " part
        Escribir ""
        num <- azar(8)+1
        numVerificar<- azar(4)+1
        Escribir "Posición " num
        
        si  num<>numVerificar
            nAzar=azar(10)+1
            Escribir "Puntos obtenidos: " nAzar
            resTotal= resTotal+nAzar
            
        FinSi
        
        si num=numVerificar Entonces
            
            resPerdi= 0 
            Escribir " ========================================"
            Escribir " |              Perdiste                |"
            Escribir " |         Posición de la bala:" numVerificar " |"
            Escribir " ========================================"
            
            Escribir "Puntos: " resPerdi
            Escribir ""                     
        FinSi
        Esperar Tecla
    FinPara
    
    Escribir ""    
FinSubproceso
```

Luego solo deberás hacer el llamado al subproceso cuando hagas el llamado al jugador.

```
    repetir
        Limpiar Pantalla
        
        Escribir "           Orden del Juego"
        Escribir  "1. inicia primer partida del jugador 1"
        Escribir  "2. inicia primer partida del segundo 2"
        Escribir  "3. inicio segunda partida del jugador 1"
        Escribir  "4. inicio segunda partida del jugador 2"
        leer opc
        
        
        Segun opc Hacer
            1:
                Escribir "***********************************************" 
                Escribir "        PRIMER JUEGO DEL PRIMER JUGADOR"
                Escribir "***********************************************"
                Escribir ""
                Escribir "   ************************"
                Escribir "   |   Jugador   " jugador1  "  |"
                Escribir "   ************************"
                Escribir ""
                disparo; 
        FinSegun
    Hasta Que resPedir = 0
```

También observé que te falto cerrar el **Segun** y también te falto cerrar el **repetir**.

Comment: gracias por el comentario, no pude agregar todo el pseudocódigo por acá por que no me lo permitió. podría enviártelo para que lo veas completo?